# Change variable every time a link clicked

Tags: jquery-selectors

links:

```
<ul id="topics">
<? while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) { ?>
<li>- <a href="#" title="<?=$row->t_topic;?>"><?=$row->t_topic;?></a></li>
<? } mysql_free_result($result); ?>
</ul>
```

jQuery code:

```
$(function() {
    $("a").click(function(){
        var title = $("a").attr("title");
        $("#main").html(title);
    });
});
```

'title' is different on every link. When I clicked a link, it doesn't read var 'title'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code needs to read the title from a specific `a` tag that was clicked upon. This simple change should do it:

```
$(function() {
    $("a").click(function(){
        var title = $(this).attr("title"); // Note "this" here
        $("#main").html(title);
    });
});
```